# NUnit runner compilation failed error with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I am not able to run tests in ReSharper 2018.2.3 after update ReScharper it self and Visual Studio till 15.8.6. Reinstall does not help.

ERROR JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.CodeDom.CompileException: NUnit runner compilation failed

> (126:90) ) expected
>
> (126:96) ; expected
>
> (126:96) Invalid expression term ')'
>
> (126:97) ; expected
>
> (126:97) Invalid expression term ')'
>
> (126:98) ; expected

Server stack trace:

> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.CodeDom.RunnerTypeCompiler.AssertCompilationResultsHaveNoErrors(CompilerResults
>   compilerResults)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.CodeDom.RunnerTypeCompiler.CompileIntoAssembly(String
>   outputPath, Assembly resourceAssembly, String[] resourcesToCompile,
>   String[] assembliesToReference)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.DelegatingTestRunner.GetRunner(String
>   nUnitInstallDir, TaskExecutorConfiguration configuration, SimpleLogger
>   logger)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.DelegatingTestRunner.RunTests(IRemoteTaskServer
>   server, List`1 assemblies, Dictionary`2 tests, Dictionary`2 fixtures,
>   List`1 explicitly, Boolean useAddins, String nUnitInstallDir,
>   TaskExecutorConfiguration configuration, SimpleLogger logger)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.INUnitRunner.RunTests(IRemoteTaskServer
>   server, List`1 assemblies, Dictionary`2 tests, Dictionary`2 fixtures,
>   List`1 explicitly, Boolean useAddins, String nUnitInstallDir,
>   TaskExecutorConfiguration configuration, SimpleLogger logger)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.Run(String
>   nUnitInstallDir, String assmbl, Boolean useAddins)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.RunTestsInAssemblies(List`1
>   assemblies, NUnitTestAssemblySetTask assemblySetTask, Boolean
>   useAddins, NUnitVersion nUnitVersion)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.ExecuteRecursive(TaskExecutionNode
>   node)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.Execute(TaskExecutionNode
>   node)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.ExecuteNodes(IEnumerable`1
>   nodes)
>
> at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.TasksPacketHandler.ThreadProc(TaskRunnerProxy
>   proxy, IEnumerable`1 packets, AssemblyLoader loader)

Comment: Do you have the checkbox "Use specified custom NUnit" ticked under "Options | Tools | Unit Testing | NUnit"?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The checkbox was checked and I had a message "NUnit versiom 3.9.0.0 is detected". I unchecked this checkbox, and it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

There is [the same issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-471333) on JetBrains public bug tracker. As a workaround, for now, untick the checkbox "Use specified custom NUnit" ticked under "ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | NUnit".

Answer (score 0):

Try to update or reinstall related with NUnit packages

```
Update-Package <package_name>
Update-Package <package_name> –reinstall
```